How to find permeability of a magnetic material?
I have been working with magnetic materials for quite some time now and never really explored this fundamental parameter. After looking through the literature I realize there and quite few different type of permeabilities (relative, initial, max). Based on my search the reported permeabilities for commercial magnetic materials are usually initial permeabilities (H=0) basically when the field is very close to zero. I have been fabricating a new material composition and wanted to calculate its permeability. I have a vibrating sample magnetometer to measure the hysteresis loops and even virgin magnetization. But what I have realized is experimental measurement of these initial permeabilities is quite difficult with a VSM. Does anyone know how this initial permeability is measured? I understand the theory and formula of calculating the value from the slope what I am asking is more about the experimental method to get the slope.
